# VBA copy value in column B based on value in colum A and paste into another sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I have a very specific request based on a spreadsheet with two columns. I want to search the values "Transaction Amount" and only the second "Name/Address" (not the first and third) field into a seperate sheet.  There are 37 of such wires in and I need it to run through each one. Any ideas?  This is what I have so far. It will copy based on transaction amount, but I also want it to copy the second name/address field and paste into the row in the next column.

Thanks!

```
Sub cond_copy()
 'assuming the data is in sheet1
Sheets("Sheet1").Select
RowCount = Cells(Cells.Rows.Count, "a").End(xlUp).Row
For i = 1 To RowCount
     'assuming the true statment is in column a
    Range("a" & i).Select
    check_value = ActiveCell
    If check_value = "Transaction Amount" Or check_value = "Transaction Amount" Then
        ActiveCell.EntireRow.Copy
         'assuming the data is in sheet2
        Sheets("Sheet2").Select
        RowCount = Cells(Cells.Rows.Count, "a").End(xlUp).Row
        Range("a" & RowCount + 1).Select
        ActiveSheet.Paste
        Sheets("Sheet1").Select
    End If
Next
```

End Sub

https://i.stack.imgur.com/vD3FZ.png

Answer (score 0):

Will the second `Name/Address` field always be 9 rows below `Transaction Amount`? If that's the case, you can try this...

Also I would recommend steering away from `.Select`. It's usually not needed, lowers performance, and from my experience, causes intermittent errors.

```
Sub cond_copy()
 'assuming the data is in sheet1
    RowCount = 1
    addressCounter = 0
    With Worksheets("Sheet1")
        For i = 1 To .Cells(.Cells.rows.Count, "a").End(xlUp).row
             'assuming the true statment is in column a
            If .Cells(i, "A").value = "Transaction Amount" Then
                For x = i + 1 To .Cells(.Cells.rows.Count, "a").End(xlUp).row
                    If .Cells(x, "A").value = "Name/Address" Then addressCounter = addressCounter + 1
                    If addressCounter = 2 Then
                        Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(RowCount, "A").value = .Cells(i, "B").value
                        Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(RowCount, "B").value = .Cells(x, "B").value
                        RowCount = RowCount + 1
                        addressCounter = 0
                        Exit For
                    End If
                Next

                i = x - 1
            End If
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: No, the problem is some of the wires have additional fields which will raise or lower the numbers of rows in between

Comment: @user2966728, Sorry for the late response. I've updated the answer to allow flexibility of the Name/Address locations. Note that the code will grab whatever value that is right next to Name/Address field (in your screenshot it will grab 'B23'. Let me know if you would need to capture the entire value of the field, 'B23:B24'.